# Merge/nest multiple PDF pages to one

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron

I'm trying to write a little electron app which nests multiple pdf files or pages to one bigger page (for saving paper when plotting a lot of CAD drawings).

Basically the unix command [pdfnup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup) from pdfjam is what I want - but due to different OS (Mac and Windows) I need a cross plattform solution.

Has anyone done something smiliar with node/javascript so far? After a lot of reasearch I haven't found a reasonable solution or library.

Comment: I have not done something similar, but the following package sounds a lot like what you are looking for: https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Embedding-pdf ... It claims to be able to merge several pdf pages into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zxifer's answer I stumbled across the [HummusRecipe](https://github.com/chunyenHuang/hummusRecipe) library which provides an high-level API to the [HummusJS](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS) project. The overlay method is what I was looking for.

I ended up with this code:

```
// Maximum plottable height (915 mm) - Conversion to point
const maxPageHeight = (915 / 0.3528);

// Read files and determine width/length of plot
const fileOne = new HummusRecipe('lp.pdf', 'output1.pdf');
const fileTwo = new HummusRecipe('ls.pdf', 'output2.pdf');
let width = Math.max(fileOne.pageInfo(1).width, fileTwo.pageInfo(1).width) + 30;

// Create new pdf file
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe('new', 'output.pdf', {
    version: 1.6,
    author: 'IBB Wörn Ingenieure GmbH',
    title: 'Print PDF',
    subject: 'Imposition of various PDF files for optimized printing.'
});

// Get height of first pdf to generate offsett
let heightOne = fileOne.pageInfo(1).height;
// Overlay PDFs to new pdf with offset and ~ 5mm margin
pdfDoc
    .createPage(width, maxPageHeight)
    .overlay('lp.pdf', 15, 15)
    .overlay('ls.pdf', 15, heightOne + 15)
    .endPage()
    .endPDF();
```